# My app is not visible in share dialog even with intent filters in place

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent, android-manifest, share-intent

I'm working with a team that's developing an app with a feature to share images into our app.

Now, when I wrote this feature on a separate project, it worked smoothly and I was able to see my test app in the share dialog of other apps. But when this feature was integrated by someone in the main project, they're not able to see the app in share dialog at all. I am pretty new to Android native development, but I'm pretty sure this has to do with conflicts in manifests.

The project is being done in Unity, with a simple jar file written by me to handle the shared data.

This is the working manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Bigthinx.Droid" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>z
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="515ca393-203c-4ab0-af59-c41a3231f421" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

And this is the main project manifest that's not working, even with the SEND intent filters in place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.bigthinx.lyflikeandroid" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner" android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:name="text/*"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:name="image/*"/>  
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.plakc.browser.PlakcBrowserActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.plakc.videoplayer.player.MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!-- This tag is required to use Google Play Services, which the IMA SDK requires -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:name="com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.PurchaseActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:enableVrMode="com.google.vr.vrcore/com.google.vr.vrcore.common.VrCoreListenerService" android:name="com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.VRPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.vr.vrcore.ACTION_NONE" />
        <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.DAYDREAM" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="cbfc80f5-baae-4ebe-b696-e499b3dfdc86" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="False" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb256950351806463" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider256950351806463" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
         The initialization ContentProvider will call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize automatically
         with the application context. This config is merged in with the host app's manifest,
         but there can only be one provider with the same authority activated at any given
         point; so if the end user has two or more different apps that use Facebook SDK, only the
         first one will be able to use the provider. To work around this problem, we use the
         following placeholder in the authority to identify each host application as if it was
         a completely different provider.
        -->
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.FacebookInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" />
  <!--  <provider 
              android:name="com.yasirkula.unity.UnitySSContentProvider"
              android:authorities="MY_UNIQUES_AUTHORITY"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true"
              />
              -->
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <!-- Indicates use of Android's VR-mode, available only on Android N+ -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="false" />
  <!-- Indicates use of VR features that are available only on official "VR-ready" devices -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.high_performance" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

I'll be glad if someone could help me and point out what's wrong in the main project manifest.

Thanks!

Comment: <data android:mimeType="text/*"/> mime type may be be restricting to send images, can you try with sharing text if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:name="text/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

`android:name` of `data` should be `android:mimeType`
It was correct in the first manifest but not the second.

Comment: Hey man it worked. Thanks! The other developer hadn't copied the intent filters correctly.